Income tax simulator with SALT deductions in the United States
I am looking for a program or webservice that can estimate the US federal and state income taxes for a taxpayer residing in the United States assuming that they takes SALT deductions and that the SALT deductions can be up to 80kUSD (as it seems it may be the case in 2022). Any license or price is fine.

What I've found so far:

https://smartasset.com/taxes/income-taxes doesn't have SALT deductions.

